# issue in uploading featured in custom post type from frontend

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="POST" action="">
          <input type="file" name="featured_img"><br/>
          <input type="submit" name="imgupdate" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </form>

    </div>


<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $update_id = get_the_ID();

    //    Update featured image

    $uploaddir  = wp_upload_dir();
    $file       = $_FILES['featured_img'];
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename($file['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    $filename    = basename($uploadfile);
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null);
    $attachment  = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
    );
    $update_img  = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $uploadfile);
    if (isset($_POST['imgupdate'])) {
        if (($_FILES['featured_img']['name'] == true)) {
            update_post_meta($update_id, '_thumbnail_id', $update_img);
        }
    }

?>
```

i want to edit featured image from the front end i want to achieve this by using this code, but it is not working .It does not updated the image. any help? where i get the problem. this code working fine on other page. but i want this in model pop up. this not working in popup. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use a plugin for display your popup ? Can we have the full source code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add code like this, it's working for me.

Hope this will also work for you.

```
 if ($_FILES) {
        array_reverse($_FILES);
        if ($_FILES['file_featured_image']) {
            $i = 0; //this will count the posts
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($i == 0)
                    $set_feature = 1; //if $i ==0 then we are dealing with the first post
                else
                    $set_feature = 0; //if $i!=0 we are not dealing with the first post

                insert_featured_image_for_property($file, $property_id, $set_feature);
                $i++; //count posts
            }
        }
  }
```

add a function in functions.php

```
function insert_featured_image_for_property($file_handler, $property_id, $setthumb = 'false') {
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    return __return_false();
}
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = media_handle_upload($file_handler, $property_id);
//set post thumbnail if setthumb is 1
if ($setthumb == 1)
    update_post_meta($property_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
return $attach_id;
}
```